# Templated function overload is failing to be called in recursive template call

Tags: c++, function, templates, overloading

I am running into an issue with getting an appropriate function template overload to be executed for some templated types. The minimal example needed to see what I'm running into is shown below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

template<typename id_type>
struct B {
    id_type ID;
    std::vector<int> values;
};

template<typename id_type>
struct A {
    id_type ID;
    std::vector<struct B<id_type>> b_elems;
};

// forward declarations
namespace aSDG {
    namespace meshing {
        template<typename id_type> size_t byte_content(const struct B<id_type>& instance);
        template<typename id_type> size_t serialize(const struct B<id_type>& instance, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0);
        template<typename id_type> size_t deserialize(struct B<id_type>& instance, const unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0);
        template<typename id_type> size_t byte_content(const struct A<id_type>& instance);
        template<typename id_type> size_t serialize(const struct A<id_type>& instance, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0);
        template<typename id_type> size_t deserialize(struct A<id_type>& instance, const unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0);
    }
}

namespace aSDG {
    namespace meshing {

        // serialization for primitive types
        template<typename T> size_t byte_content(const T& data){
            return sizeof(T);
        }

        template<typename T> size_t serialize(const T& data, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0)
        {
            std::memcpy((void*)(buffer + start_idx), (void*)&data, sizeof(data));
            return start_idx + sizeof(data);
        }
        template<typename T> size_t deserialize(T& data, const unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0)
        {
            std::memcpy((void*)&data, (void*)(buffer + start_idx), sizeof(data));
            return start_idx + sizeof(data);
        }

        // serialization for vector containers
        template<typename T> size_t byte_content(const std::vector<T>& data){

            // get number of bytes for the size variable
            size_t num_req_bytes = sizeof(size_t);

            // get the number of bytes for each element of the vector
            for(size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i){
                num_req_bytes += byte_content(data[i]);
            }// end for i

            // return the total number of required bytes
            return num_req_bytes;
        }

        template<typename T> size_t serialize(const std::vector<T>& data, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0)
        {
            // add the number of elements in the data
            const size_t size_ = data.size();
            start_idx = serialize(size_, buffer, start_idx);

            // add the actual data elements
            for(size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i){
                start_idx = serialize(data[i], buffer, start_idx);
            }// end for i

            // return the final index after adding all the data
            return start_idx;
        }

        template<typename T> size_t deserialize(std::vector<T>& data, const unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0)
        {
            // get the number of elements in the array
            size_t size_ = 0;
            start_idx = deserialize(size_, buffer, start_idx);

            // resize the input array
            data.resize(size_);

            // fill the array with the data in the buffer
            for(size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i){
                start_idx = deserialize(data[i], buffer, start_idx);
            }// end for i

            // return the number of bytes we are at in the array
            return start_idx;
        }

    } // end namespace meshing
} // end namespace aSDG

namespace aSDG {
    namespace meshing {

        // serialization for B
        template<typename id_type>
        size_t byte_content(const struct B<id_type>& instance) {
            return byte_content(instance.ID) + byte_content(instance.values);
        }

        template<typename id_type>
        size_t serialize(const struct B<id_type>& instance, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx){
            start_idx = serialize(instance.ID, buffer, start_idx);
            return serialize(instance.values, buffer, start_idx);
        }

        template<typename id_type>
        size_t deserialize(struct B<id_type>& instance, const unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx){
            start_idx = deserialize(instance.ID, buffer, start_idx);
            return deserialize(instance.values, buffer, start_idx);
        }

        // serialization functions for A
        template<typename id_type>
        size_t byte_content(const struct A<id_type>& instance) {
            return byte_content(instance.ID) + byte_content(instance.b_elems);
        }

        template<typename id_type>
        size_t serialize(const struct A<id_type>& instance, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx){
            start_idx = serialize(instance.ID, buffer, start_idx);
            return serialize(instance.b_elems, buffer, start_idx);
        }

        template<typename id_type>
        size_t deserialize(struct A<id_type>& instance, const unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx){
            start_idx = deserialize(instance.ID, buffer, start_idx);
            return deserialize(instance.b_elems, buffer, start_idx);
        }


    } // end namespace meshing
} // end namespace aSDG



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct A<size_t> a1, a2;
    a1.b_elems.emplace_back();
    a1.b_elems.emplace_back();
    a1.b_elems.emplace_back();
    a1.b_elems[0].ID = 5;
    a1.b_elems[0].values.push_back(1);

    // get the number of bytes to be serialized
    size_t num_req_bytes = aSDG::meshing::byte_content(a1);

    // allocate the buffer
    std::vector<unsigned char> buf( num_req_bytes );

    // serialize the data in a1
    size_t serial_bytes = aSDG::meshing::serialize(a1, &buf[0]);

    // deserialize data into a2
    size_t deserial_bytes= aSDG::meshing::deserialize(a2, &buf[0]);

    // check that the bytes match
    printf("in_bytes = %zu vs. out_bytes = %zu\n", serial_bytes, deserial_bytes );

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, I go to serialize an instance of the type `A` and this serialization in turn requires serializing the vector of `B` elements contained within `A`. All of the serialization functions for `A` run, meaning its flavor of `byte_content`, `serialize` and `deserialize` get called with the appropriate definitions. However, when the program recurses to the generic `std::vector` definition of those methods to serialize the `std::vector<struct B>` data member of `A`, it is failing to call the methods defined for `B` and is instead calling the serialization functions for basic primitives (the first three defined at the top of the code sample). I cannot see why the serialization methods (`byte_content`, `serialize`, `deserialize`) for `B` are not being called in this situation since they are defined.

I suspect I am missing some fundamental rule for how function template overloads are chosen but I really am not sure. Any insight would be appreciated.

**Edit 1**

To be more precise, the key issue is that when the serialization of `A` happens, it will in fact call the expected method below

```
template<typename id_type>
size_t aSDG::meshing::serialize(const struct A<id_type>& instance, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0){
    start_idx = serialize(instance.ID, buffer, start_idx);
    return serialize(instance.b_elems, buffer, start_idx);
}
```

The problem is, when it goes to serialize the `b_elems`, it first calls the generic `std::vector` serialization method with `T = struct B`

```
template<typename T> size_t serialize(const std::vector<T>& data, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0)
{
    // add the number of elements in the data
    const size_t size_ = data.size();
    start_idx = serialize(size_, buffer, start_idx);

    // add the actual data elements
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i){
        start_idx = serialize(data[i], buffer, start_idx);
    }// end for i

    // return the final index after adding all the data
    return start_idx;
}
```

but then when it goes to do `serialize(data[i], buffer, start_idx)`, the function does not call

```
template<typename id_type>
size_t serialize(const struct B<id_type>& instance, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0){
    start_idx = serialize(instance.ID, buffer, start_idx);
    return serialize(instance.values, buffer, start_idx);
}
```

but instead calls

```
template<typename T> size_t serialize(const T& data, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx = 0)
{
    std::memcpy((void*)(buffer + start_idx), (void*)&data, sizeof(data));
    return start_idx + sizeof(data);
}
```

I am really confused as to why this is happening.

**Edit 2**

After adding forward declarations recommended by @Evg, the code almost works as I would expect. The only problem now is that the `byte_content` specialization for `B` is not being called. One can verify this by replacing the above specialization definitions for `B` with

```
template<typename id_type>
size_t byte_content(const struct B<id_type>& instance) {
    printf("B byte_content\n");
    return byte_content(instance.ID) + byte_content(instance.values);
}

template<typename id_type>
size_t serialize(const struct B<id_type>& instance, unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx){
    printf("B serialize\n");
    start_idx = serialize(instance.ID, buffer, start_idx);
    return serialize(instance.values, buffer, start_idx);
}

template<typename id_type>
size_t deserialize(struct B<id_type>& instance, const unsigned char* buffer, size_t start_idx){
    printf("B deserialize\n");
    start_idx = deserialize(instance.ID, buffer, start_idx);
    return deserialize(instance.values, buffer, start_idx);
}
```

and witness that the "B byte_content" message is never shown. Now maybe I'm just tired and not seeing some error but I cannot see why, even after the forward declaration, the correct `byte_content` specialization for `B` is not being called.

Comment: Put forward declarations of specialized functions before generic ones.

Comment: @Evg I just updated things after I saw your brief answer (that's not longer there), but let me try what you just said because that rings a bell in my head.

Comment: This answer was not correct, so I removed it. I reread your question and saw the real problem. The problem is that inside generic method the compiler doesn't know about specialized ones. Use forward declarations of them.

Comment: @Evg it is super close to working, but if you see my edit I am finding that one of the function specializations is still not being called and I am really surprised after your recommendation since the other function specializations are working now. I feel like I may just have some stupid mistake but I cannot see anything.

Comment: I see the message "B byte_content" after I make the proposed replacement.

Comment: @Evg nevermind, I figured it out. In the code on my computer, I had `byte_content<T>(...)` in the loop part of the `std::vector` specialization of `byte_content` and for some reason that `<T>` was causing the difference. I honestly do not know why removing the `<T>` makes the difference, but it did (when I got it to match what I had on here).

Comment: @Evg wow okay, awesome. I had no clue about the ADL lookup fact. Thank you so much for your help! This has been very useful for me.

Comment: @Evg yeah I know, I just felt like writing them I guess lol.

Comment: Next time please don't make significant changes to the code in your question. It really makes hard to understand what the answer is about for those who'll find this question later.

Comment: The comment about ADL for `<T>` was incorrect. Inside the loop, `T` is `B<id_type>`, but in the template you need, `T` is `id_type`. So it doesn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this answer refers to the question before it was edited (no forward declarations).

Inside `serialize(const std::vector<T>& data...)` you use an unqualified name `serialize`. The compiler should decide which `serialize` to call. It will consider functions 1) which are visible at the point of definition and 2) which can be found by ADL at the point of instantiation. Both lookups will fail to find `serialize(const B<id_type>&...)`.

One possible solution is to put forward declarations

```
template<typename id_type>
size_t byte_content(const B<id_type>&);

template<typename id_type>
size_t serialize(const B<id_type>&, unsigned char*, size_t = 0);

template<typename id_type>
size_t deserialize(B<id_type>&, const unsigned char*, size_t = 0);
```

at the very beginning.